# Get the closest squares in a grid-like system

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grid, path-finding

I have a chess-like grid system and I would like to build an algorithm to get the squares in a given range around a given tile, assuming that the distance should be calculated in a *cross-like* fashion (diagonals count 2).

So, given that the circle is the central point, here is an example image:

[image: Grid system with cross-like distance]

I have found this solution (I am using javascript):

```
function findRange(tile, range){

    var tiles = [];
    for(row = 0; row < rows; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < cols; col++){
        if( (Math.abs(row - tile.y) + Math.abs(col - tile.x)) <= range )
          tiles.push([col,row]);
      }
    }
    return tiles;

  }
```

Basically, I loop through all the tiles and then compare the sum of the absolute value difference of the coordinates to my range. I mean, it works (to my surprise); but, for some reason **it doesn't feel right**, it feels a bit **gimmicky** and also is probably less than optimal to loop every single tile: though I am working with small grids and I don't think that looping those is an expensive operation.

On the plus side, the code is really small.

I asked a friend of mine who is into game developing to come out with a solution to this problem and he suggested this (in C++):

```
Node *GetNodeAt(float x, float y)
{    
    float width = m_nodeSize * m_columns;
    float height = m_nodeSize * m_rows;

    if( x < 0.0f || y < 0.0f || 
        x >= width || y >= height)
        return nullptr;

    int r = y/m_nodeSize;
    int c = x/m_nodeSize;
    int target = (m_columns*r + c);

    return &m_nodesArray[target];
}

std::list<Node*> GetCrossArea(Node *origin, int range, bool addOriginNode)
{
    std::list<Node*> area;
    Node *n;
    for(int k = range; k >= -range; k--)    
    {
        n = GetNodeAt(origin->GetPosition().x + m_nodeSize * k, origin->GetPosition().y);

        if(k == range || k == -range)
            area.push_back(n);
        else
        {
            if(n != origin)
                area.push_back(n);
            else if(addOriginNode)
                area.push_back(n);

            Node *nVert;
            int verticalSteps = (range - abs(k));
            for(int q = verticalSteps; q > 0; q--)
            {
                nVert = GetNodeAt(n->GetPosition().x, n->GetPosition().y + m_nodeSize * verticalSteps);
                area.push_back(nVert);
                nVert = GetNodeAt(n->GetPosition().x, n->GetPosition().y + (1 - m_nodeSize) * verticalSteps);
                area.push_back(nVert);
                verticalSteps--;

            }
        }       
    }
    return area;
}
```

### Questions

Is there a better-known algorithm to solve this problem? If not, which of the proposed solutions is better? Am I missing something completely obvious in my approach?

Comment: If your grid is small, you should consider to pre-compute the 64 node lists, so there's no need for an 'algorithm'. If your grid is big, then your filtering approach (calculating the distance for every node in the grid) is clearly ineffective.

Comment: Building upon @mkluwe's comment, you may want to use the nested loop in your first code segment to initialise the node lists and then index into that node list which will be a very cheap O(1) operation. Caching things like that is very common in chess too. One drawback however, is maintaining the node list in memory all time.

Comment: Your "cross-like fashion" sounds like you're talking about "[Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)".

Comment: Just do a breadth-first search.

Comment: @bytefire I actually store the node list into a two-dimensional array, like `nodeList[x][y]` for convenience. Looping through this would require again a nested loop. Do you suggest to store the node list into a simple one-dimensional array? Do you think it is a big of a drawback can be maintaining the node list into the memory all time (let's say for a 100x100 grid, it is indeed 10000 objects)?

Comment: Thank you @Stobor ! Apparently that was what I was talking about.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Care to elaborate how would I implement that? I'd be grateful!

Comment: One-dimensional array will be faster than two-dimensional. But it should be possible to access nodeList[i][j] without iterating, if each square is identified by its index number. Regarding size in memory, it depends how big each of those 10,000 objects is and what sort of hardware will the code run on. If the object is just an integer (for distance between the two squares) then 40kB (10000 * 4 bytes) should be fine on most modern computers. However this size can be easily brought down to 10kB by storing the distance in byte instead of Int32.

Answer (score 1):

How about only hitting the tiles you need?

For all the tiles less than or equal to `range` distance away:

```
function findRange(tile, range){

    var tiles = [];

    starty = Math.max(0,      (tile.y - range));
    endy = Math.min(rows - 1, (tile.y + range));

    for(row = starty ; row <= endy ; row++){

        xrange = range - Math.abs(row - tile.y);

        startx = Math.max(0,      (tile.x - xrange));
        endx = Math.min(cols - 1, (tile.x + xrange));

        for(col = startx ; col <= endx ; col++){
            tiles.push([col,row]);
         }
     }

     return tiles;

}
```

## Rationale:

The goal to find all the cells which satisfy this condition:

```
 (Math.abs(row - tile.y) + Math.abs(col - tile.x)) <= range
```

Because the result of `Math.abs(col - tile.x)` can never be negative, we know we only have to look at those cells in rows which satisfy

```
 Math.abs(row - tile.y) <= range
```

which is equivalent to

```
 tile.y - range <= row <= tile.y + range
```

To account for the edges of the grid, we have to cap these ranges at 0 and `rows - 1` - so it becomes

```
 Math.max(0, (tile.y - range)) <= row <= Math.min(rows - 1, (tile.y + range))
```

So the first for loop is starts at `Math.max(0, (tile.y - range))` and finishes at `Math.min(rows - 1, (tile.y + range))`

Now, once you have picked a row, we consider which columns will satisfy our first condition:

```
 (Math.abs(row - tile.y) + Math.abs(col - tile.x)) <= range
```

which is equivalent to

```
 Math.abs(col - tile.x) <= range - Math.abs(row - tile.y)
```

which is further equvalent to

```
 tile.x - (range - Math.abs(row - tile.y))
      <= col <= 
 tile.x + (range - Math.abs(row - tile.y))
```

And again, accounting for edges,

```
 Math.min(0, (tile.x - (range - Math.abs(row - tile.y)))) 
      <= col <= 
 Math.max(cols - 1, (tile.x + (range - Math.abs(row - tile.y))))
```

to make it a little clearer, pull out the common `(range - Math.abs(row - tile.y))` bit and call it `xrange` to get

```
 Math.min(0, (tile.x - xrange)) 
      <= col <= 
 Math.max(cols - 1, (tile.x + xrange))
```

Comment: Interesting answer. So you say that my first intuition about using the absolute difference is the way to go, but we should limit the loop to the fewer tiles we could afford, right? Certainly a performance improvement of my solution… though it is still a nested loop, and I am not sure I understand the second part.

Comment: For the record, to make it work, you have to change the loop like so: **`for(row = startY ; row <= endY ; row++`** or the last row will be missing.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva Yep, I typed that up while falling asleep, so I knew I had to double-check the boundary conditions. As for it being a nested loop, it is specifically only touching the cells it needs to, and absolutely not considering any cells outside the required range. I can't see how you could get much more efficient than that. I'll try to put up a better rationale later.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline for an answer

First take a good hard look at the patterns in your diagram.  Note that it's symmetrical about vertical and horizontal lines through `(0,0)`.  (It's also symmetrical about the diagonals through the same point but I'll ignore that for the time being).  Of course, I use `(0,0)` in a relative sense.

Second, consider only the quadrant to the NE of the (relative) centre of interest.  To find the cells at distance 1 add 1 to each of the coordinates in turn.  The cells at distance 2 from the origin are those at distance 1 from the cells at distance 1 from the origin (never decreasing coordinates to avoid going backwards and implementing some rule to prevent double counting of the cell at relative `(1,1)` ).  The cells at distance 3 ... by now you should get the idea.  It's kind of recursive.

Once you've figured out the coordinates of the cells of interest in the NE quadrant, reflect them about the vertical line through (relative) `(0,0)` and about the horizontal line through the same cell, and about both lines.

I ignored the symmetry about the diagonals because it's a bit more tricky to rotate the cell indices about 45° than to reflect them through the orthogonal axes.

I'll leave it to a better Javascript programmer than I am (or wish to be) to turn this into code.

**EDIT**

Without loss of generality let the origin of the region of interest be at cell `(0,0)` and the radius of the interest be `R`.  Then the loop

```
do r = 0, R
    do s = 0, r
        pushTile([s,r-s])
    end do
end do
```

should, if I've done my calculations correctly, push the sequence

```
`(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3), ...`
```

and these are the coordinates of the cells at distances `0,1,2,3,...` from the origin.

This isn't a recursive algorithm as I thought it might be earlier, I don't see the need for recursion now.

Once the loops have finished you have the coordinates of all the cells in the NE quadrant including both its axes, ie all the cells with coordinates which are both non-negative.  First reflect around the vertical axis, for every cell with a +ve x-coordinate insert the cell `(-x,y)` into the list.  Then reflect around the horizontal axis: for every cell with a +ve y-coordinate add the cell `(x,-y)` into the list.

If the origin of the region of interest is not at `(0,0)` then compute the offset from the centre to `(0,0)`, run the calculation outlined above, then apply the offset in the other direction.

Comment: I tried to turn this approach into code, because I liked the rationale behind it. However, I come out with ugly code (perhaps my implementation fault), duplicates (the non-diagonal squares are duplicated, I can avoid it but then I'd have to implement a rule to prevent double counting, as you mentioned), and also I don't get an axis quite right (I can't seem to manage to prove your assumption that **cells at distance 2 from the origin are those at distance 1 from the cells at distance 1 from the origin**). Any ideas?

Comment: So… I have implemented this idea [**like so**](http://jsbin.com/ogisec/4/edit) (you can run it and see the results on the `console`). It works: I feel my implementation might receive some optimization, though (like, see that `if` statement? Yuck!). Also, I am not sure that this is the way you thought it would work; if yes, how is this solution more efficient/performant than my solution as optimized by @Stobor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but I just had to solve this problem so I thought I'd post this solution, IMO a bit cleaner than others. It uses the "solve in one quadrant" approach but avoids having to deal with double-visits/etc.

```
//<visit the starting tile u,v here>
for(d=1; d <= max_dist; d++)
{ 
    for(i=0; i < d; i++)
    {
        j = d-i;
        //<visit tiles (u+i,v+j), (u+j,v-i), (u-i,v-j), (u-j,v+i) here>
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this, an algorithm is actually not entirely necessary. All you need to know is the origin's coordinates, and then from there get the squares around. BTW, the array for the tiles must go in the order of rows, then cols for this to work.

```
function getSurroundingTiles(tiles, originY, originX) {
    var newTiles = [];

    if (tiles[originY + 1][originX - 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY + 1][originX - 1]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY + 1][originX]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY + 1][originX]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY + 1][originX + 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY + 1][originX + 1]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY][originX + 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY][originX + 1]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY - 1][originX + 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY - 1][originX + 1]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY - 1][originX]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY - 1][originX]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY - 1][originX - 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY - 1][originX - 1]);
    }

    if (tiles[originY][originX - 1]) {
        newTiles.push(tiles[originY][originX - 1]);
    }

    return newTiles;
}
```

Comment: *an algorithm is actually not entirely necessary* and then you go on to write a program implementing an algorithm.  I invite you to post a code which does not employ an algorithm.